# Laravel Scout, search with where clausure

Tags: laravel, search, where-clause

I just discovered Laravel Scout and I wanted to make a search with where clausure. The code shown below

```
$notes = Note::search($request->lecturer_search)->where([
            ['course_id','=',$course_id],
            ['course_code_number', '=', $request->course_code_number_search]
        ])->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(5);
```

But I'm getting this error:

Type error: Too few arguments to function Laravel\Scout\Builder::where(), 1 passed in /home/vagrant/www/Bee/app/Http/Controllers/SearchController.php on line 36 and exactly 2 expected

When I remove where clausure, there is no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scout has it's own `where()` method which accepts just two parameters: field and value. So do this:

```
->where('course_id', $course_id)
->where('course_code_number', $request->course_code_number_search)
```

Instead of this:

```
->where([
    ['course_id','=',$course_id],
    ['course_code_number', '=', $request->course_code_number_search]
])
```

You can look at the source code of the `where()` method [here](https://github.com/laravel/scout/blob/3.0/src/Builder.php#L98).

Answer (score 1):

I generate to queries.
One via relational search. And on with scout.
Then I reduce the relational results with the results of the scout search.

In your case:

```
$notes = Note::where([
    ['course_id','=',$course_id],
    ['course_code_number', '=', $request->course_code_number_search]
]);
$notesSearchResults = Note::search($request->lecturer_search);
$searchResultIds = $notesSearchResults->map(function ($item, $key) {
            return $item['id'];
        });
$notes = $notes->whereIn('notes.id', $searchResultIds)->get();
```